# Destructor of flann::Index after copy constructor produces access violation

Tags: c++, flann

EDIT (thanks to Barry in comments) I need to copy FLANN search indices to use them in a vector but it is producing an access violation when the copies go range. The minimal code that crashes is:

```
#include<flann\flann.hpp>
#include<vector>
const int samplesize=10;
const int dimension=3;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //fill a pointer to doubles with whatever
    double * data=new double[samplesize*dimension];
        for(int i=0; i<samplesize*dimension; ++i)
        {
            data[i]=1;
        }
// make a FLANN search index from that data
flann::Matrix<double> datamat(data,samplesize,dimension );
flann::Index<flann::L2<double> > ind(datamat, flann::KDTreeIndexParams(4));

flann::Index<flann::L2<double> > ind2(ind);


return 0;
}
```

I would be grateful if anyone can tell me how to stop this

Comment: I'm not familiar with `flann::Index`, but is the problem that you have two copies of `ind` getting destroyed? If you replace the vector with just `flann::Index<...> ind2(ind);`, do you still get the double-delete?

Comment: @Barry ah yes `flann::Index<flann::L2<double> > ind2(ind);` does make the same error. Also it calls std::~vector which explains why the original code was going there twice. I shall edit the question

Comment: Could you edit the question again to show what the problem is _now_? (Oh and the title as well to keep it coherent :) )

Comment: @ JBL OK, I have made those edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be that I just shouldn't use the copy constructor for Index because it copies a pointer and the destructor deletes that pointer (the FLANN programmers violated the rule of three). Working around it with a vector of pointers (or boost shared pointers) seems to do what I need